# Getting the maximum value per column in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to get the highest value for columns A, B, and C and tie those values to the date and times they occured. To get the max value i just need to use the List::Util module, but i am not sure how to point it to a particular column in the array then reference the date and time.

```
DATE    TIME    A   B   C
11/22/14    21:00:00    5,854   2,105   1,290
11/22/14    21:02:35    7,692   2,593   2,649
11/22/14    21:05:10    1,639   458 444
11/22/14    21:07:00    1,032   487 434
11/22/14    21:08:15    4,707   1,352   646
11/22/14    21:10:22    351 46  162
11/22/14    21:10:55    5,507   1,943   957
11/22/14    21:11:00    1,703   647 516
11/22/14    21:12:00    2,359   751 785
11/22/14    21:14:05    67  25  44
11/22/14    21:16:25    4,072   1,596   1,050
11/22/14    21:17:48    5,060   2,131   1,996
11/22/14    21:19:00    341 42  137
11/22/14    21:23:00    1,308   71  634
```

Comment: The input is a file ?

Comment: another command is ran prior to gather the data, however, i, have no control how the data is presented.

Comment: Please explain the output that you would like

Comment: sputnick, i don't have any code for the array and i am not looking for a whole program. I just have no idea how setup an array that allows me to grab data over 3 separate columns. when i do use the max() function, i need the output to look like this:



11/22/14    21:02:35    7,692 max for column A,

11/22/14    21:02:35    2,593 max for column B,

11/22/14    21:02:35    2,649 max for column C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding:

You want three pieces of data at the end:

- The date and time for the highest number in column A
- The date and time for the highest number in column B
- The date and time for the highest number in column C

You don't want to sort the data. You don't need to store anything else.

You didn't specify any code, so I'm not going to give you a complete program. You need to try that yourself. Instead, I'll give you some hints:

You should read up on [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and how they work. We'll store your data in a reference:

```
my %data;
$data{A}->{time} = "xxxxx";   # Time of highest item in column "A"
$data{A}->{date} = "xxxxx";   # Date of highest item in column "A"
$data{A}->{value} = "xxxx";   # Value of highest item in column "A"
```

Same with the other two columns.

You can loop through your data (is it a file? You didn't explain)

```
my %data;
while ( my $line .... ) {
    my ( $date, $time, a_value, b_value, c_value ) = split /\s*/, $line;
    if ( not exists $data{A}->{value} or $a_value > $data{A}->{value} ) {
        $data{A}->{value} = $a_value;
        $data{A}->{date}  = $date;
        $data{A}->{time}  = $time;
    }
    ...    # Same for B and C
```

In this loop, I set `$data{A}->{value`} to the value I just read in if that value is higher than the one I had previously stored. It's a common way of looking for the highest value. I also need to store it if that value doesn't already exist. Thus, I check to see if `$data{A}->{value}` exists or not. If it doesn't, I need to store that value anyway. (I could have done just `if ( not exists $data{A} or $a_value > $data{A}->{value} )`).

After your while loop, `%data` will contain the highest values of each column, and the date and time for those values. There's a lot of code repetition. I could have added an inner loop for each column, but it's not worth the effort with just three columns.

Also, remember not to include your header column in your data.

If `$data{A}->{value}` confuses you, you can use three separate hashes: One to store the date , one to store the time, and one to store the value.

```
my %times;
my %dates
my %values;
while ( my $line .... ) {
    my ( $date, $time, a_value, b_value, c_value ) = split /\s*/, $line;
    if ( not exists $values{A} or $a_value > $values{A} ) {
        $values{A} = $a_value;
        $dates{A}  = $date;
        $times{A}  = $time;
    }
    ...    # Same for B and C
```

Answer (score 1):

This might resemble Schwartzian transform in a way to reduce some overhead due lines splitting, and it uses `reduce()` from `List::Util` core module to pick just a line with max value,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'reduce';

(undef, my @tmp) = map { tr/,/./; [ $_, split ] } <DATA>;

my ($max_a) = 
  map $_->[0],
  reduce {
    $a->[3] > $b->[3] ? $a : $b
  }
  @tmp;

my ($max_b) = 
  map $_->[0],
  reduce {
    $a->[4] > $b->[4] ? $a : $b
  }
  @tmp;

my ($max_c) = 
  map $_->[0],
  reduce {
    $a->[5] > $b->[5] ? $a : $b
  }
  @tmp;

print
  "maxA: ", $max_a,
  "maxB: ", $max_b,
  "maxC: ", $max_c;

__DATA__
DATE    TIME    A   B   C
11/22/14    21:00:00    5,854   2,105   1,290
11/22/14    21:02:35    7,692   2,593   2,649
11/22/14    21:05:10    1,639   458 444
11/22/14    21:07:00    1,032   487 434
11/22/14    21:08:15    4,707   1,352   646
11/22/14    21:10:22    351 46  162
11/22/14    21:10:55    5,507   1,943   957
11/22/14    21:11:00    1,703   647 516
11/22/14    21:12:00    2,359   751 785
11/22/14    21:14:05    67  25  44
11/22/14    21:16:25    4,072   1,596   1,050
11/22/14    21:17:48    5,060   2,131   1,996
11/22/14    21:19:00    341 42  137
11/22/14    21:23:00    1,308   71  634
```

output

```
maxA: 11/22/14    21:10:22    351 46  162
maxB: 11/22/14    21:12:00    2.359   751 785
maxC: 11/22/14    21:10:55    5.507   1.943   957
```

Some refactoring,

```
sub get_max {
  my ($pos, $r) = @_;

  return map $_->[0],
    reduce {
      $a->[$pos] > $b->[$pos] ? $a : $b
    }
    @$r;
}

my ($max_a) = get_max(3, \@tmp);
my ($max_b) = get_max(4, \@tmp);
my ($max_c) = get_max(5, \@tmp);
```

Comment: Isn't the maximum "A" column `7,692`? Maybe if commas were removed `tr/,/./` ==> `tr/,//d` ?

Comment: @G.Cito good point, OP should tell whether are these thousands or decimal places.

Comment: Easier if the latter :-) For some reason just deleting the `,` with  `tr/,//d` gives the wrong result ... (it prints the maxium column values in each column of the output) and I can't figure out why  ... and figuring that out has become more interesting than the question :-)

Comment: they are commas, are you using reduce to do A/B comparisons down the list of numbers?

i was going to use max() because i wanted it to just grab the highest number in each column A, B, and C..

Comment: @Newbie_Mark you can't just use `max` if you want to _"tie those values to the date and times"_

Comment: @mpapec Excellent "refactoring" example/exercise - we can see into your mind :-) I simplified things a bit in my attempt (I can get the maximum value be sorting!) and tried to capture the change in an "edit" but I really like the refactoring presentation ++

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mechanical, procedural, and slightly more advanced than "baby perl" approach. The script is fairly simple and sticks to known perl "idioms".

- First we slurp all of `DATA` into `@lines` - an array of arrays - using `map` - we could use a `while (<DATA>){...}` loop here instead. We remove the commas while we are here (`tr/,//d`)
- We then use per-column temporary arrays (`@atmp`, `@btmp`, ...) and populate them with a direct `sort` of `@lines`, accessing the relevant column in the internal anonymous array (`$a->[n] ...`) for the `sort` operation: this way we don't use a module and avoid using `map`.
- Once we have (reverse) sorted the arrays by column, we can print the first element to get the highest value for each column. To print, we ***[dereference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)*** the first element (*e.g.* `@{$atmp[0]}` since it is an anonymous array) to get back the whole line - that way we keep the "highest value" together with the other columns for our output.

**NB** to highlight the columnar sort I changed the original data so that different lines appear as the maximum for each column. In the original data the second line has the highest value for all three columns. I'm using `tr|,||d` instead of `tr/,//d` only to unbreak the SO syntax highlighter.

```perl
use v5.16;   # adds strict and warnings

my @lines = map { tr|,||d; [ split ] } <DATA> ; 
shift @lines;   # removes header

my @atmp = sort{ $b->[2]<=>$a->[2] } @lines;     
my @btmp = sort{ $b->[3]<=>$a->[3] } @lines;     
my @ctmp = sort{ $b->[4]<=>$a->[4] } @lines ;   

print "\t DATE     TIME    A    B    C \n";
print "Max A: @{$atmp[0]}\nMax B: @{$btmp[0]}\nMax C: @{$ctmp[0]}\n" ;  

__DATA__    
DATE    TIME    A   B   C     
11/22/14    21:00:00    5,854   2,105   1,290    
11/22/14    21:02:35    7,692   2,593   2,649    
11/22/14    21:05:10    1,639   458 444  
11/22/14    21:07:00    1,032   487 434
11/22/14    21:08:15    4,707   1,352   6460 
11/22/14    21:10:22    351 46  162 
11/22/14    21:10:55    5,507   9,943   957  
11/22/14    21:11:00    1,703   647 516  
11/22/14    21:12:00    2,359   751 785      
11/22/14    21:14:05    67  25  44          
11/22/14    21:16:25    4,072   1,596   1,050 
11/22/14    21:17:48    5,060   2,131   1,996    
11/22/14    21:19:00    341 42  137 
11/22/14    21:23:00    1,308   71  634
```

**output**:

```
~/$ perl sort_by_column.pl

         DATE     TIME    A    B    C 
Max A: 11/22/14 21:02:35 7692 2593 2649
Max B: 11/22/14 21:10:55 5507 9943 957
Max C: 11/22/14 21:08:15 4707 1352 6460
```

---

- To better understand the data structures created by the perl `use DDP;` followed by `p @lines` , `p @atmp` *etc.* can be a helpful tool for "visualization".  See [`Data::Printer`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer/) for more details.

Comment: **NB** I removed the commas in each number to convert the values to integers and for some reason I'm getting odd results (see comment on @mpapec's post above). I will edit to improve "elegance" print full results and remove temporary variables.

Comment: You're getting correct results although maximal values have lost their corresponding dates/times. https://eval.in/229491

Comment: Just a quick try at it - I needed to think more about how to keep the get the rest of the line but errors kept cropping up (c.f. my comments above on your post). If I can't fix it I'll take it down.

Comment: @mpapec fixed it by just leaving them together in the first place :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Сухой27 fixed it but had you mixed  up with mpapec

Comment: Yes, I saw it already but can't upvote twice. :) (you didn't mix up anything I've changed the nick)